# Retrieving value from specific XML field

Tags: powershell, xpath

I have an xml file which I received from Invoke-RestMethod:

```
$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $body
```

XML:

```
<Body>
  <Response>
    <result>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <id>012345</id>
          <rev>
            <value>x1</value>
            <ignore>false</ignore>
          </rev>
          <type>
            <value>Zw379E01-2362-48A3</value>
          </type>
          <attributes>
            <attribute>
              <id>
                <value>1B2C-3D4E-5G6H</value>
              </id>
              <name>ID</name>
              <values>
                <value>5B3CD8E2-746A-54993</value>
              </values>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <id>
                <value>77BB84E18-F048-350CCC-E040</value>
              </id>
              <name>Updated</name>
              <values>
                <value>08.2019</value>
              </values>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <id>
                <value>1111-2222-3333</value>
              </id>
              <name>Name</name>
              <values>
                <value>TEST</value>
              </values>
            </attribute>
          </attributes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
        ...
        </resource>
        <resource>
        ...
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </result>
  </Response>
</Body>
```

There are several "resource" Blocks. 
I need to extract "id"(Body.Response.result.resources.resource.id ) on condition that attributes.attribute.values.value = TEST

I can extract all values for "id" by:

```
$request.SelectNodes("//id")
```

But I was not able to filter it as on example below:

```
$request.SelectNodes("//id") | ?{$_./attributes/attribute/values/value -eq "TEST"}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `SelectNodes("//resource[attributes/attribute/values/value[. = 'TEST']]").id`

Comment: That'll do, @MathiasR.Jessen, that'll do.  Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll want to select here is a `resource` node where the `attributes` section contain a `attribute` with value = `"TEST"` and then grab the id from said resource. The inner selection clause goes into `[]` in the XPath filter:

```
$request.SelectNodes('//resource[attributes/attribute/values/value[. = "TEST"]]').id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Mathias, but for some reason it does not give me any output...even if I try to assign it to $var and display it:

$var = $request.SelectNodes('//resource[attributes/attribute/values/value[. = "TEST"]]').id

Comment: @drBerzelius I'd double-check your `$request` variable.  Following your code example in the question, this worked without issue for me.

Comment: @drBerzelius I'd suggest removing the `.id` at the end when you're testing, but I concur with TheIncorrigible1, if the XML is indeed like what you posted this should work